# referencing a column with reactive input variable in Shiny

Tags: r, user-input, shiny

Trying to use an input variable value to reference the indicated column within the "results" data frame using the lm function in Shiny.  i've tested this in the console and it works fine but not when i actually run the app.

I don't think all of the code is necessary (but i will be happy to include more if need be) so here is the important bits from server.r:

```
compareVar2 <- reactive({
    if(input$compareVar2 == 'first'){
        return (results$firstPostScore)
    }else if(input$compareVar2 == 'last'){
        return (results$lastPostScore)
    }else if(input$compareVar2 == 'avg'){
        return (results$avgPostScore)
    }else {return (results$avgPostScore)} #just as a fall-back default

output$analysis <- renderPrint({
    analysis <- lm(preScore ~ compareVar2, data = results)
    return (summary(analysis))
})
```

I get the following error message:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = preScore ~ compareVar2, data = results, : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable 'compareVar2'

I can't seem to find anything specific to this anywhere :-/

THANKS!

Comment: attempt 2:  changed "return (results$firstPostScore)" to just "return("firstPostScore")" (and similar for all potential return values) and changed lm function to "lm(preScore ~ results[compareVar2], data = results)

got following error message:  "Error in '[.default'(results, compareVar2) : invalid subscript type 'closure'"

Comment: attempt 3: kept the return values for compareVar2 the same but changed lm function to:  "lm(preScore ~ results[names(results) == compareVar2], data = results) 

"Error in names(results) == compareVar2 : comparison (1) is possibl only for atomic and list types"

Comment: attempt 4: kept return values for compareVar2 but changed lm function to:
lm(preScore ~ names(results)[names(results) == compareVar2], data = results)

Error in names(results == compareVar2 : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compareVar2 is a function, so you should call it as compareVar2():

```
analysis <- lm(preScore ~ compareVar2(), data = results)
```

Comment: Don't worry, I've made the same mistake and was debugging for hours, only to realize I forgot the parentheses.